# 3 dimensional diode $E$ field profile

Tags: electric-fields, symmetry, semiconductor-physics, gauss-law

While deriving the electric field profile of a diode, 1D Gauss's Law is typically used:

$$\frac{dE}{dx}= \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}.$$

However, the diode is at least 2-dimentional and, in real world, even 3-dimentional.

**So how can we use a 1D equation to model this, when it should be at least 2D?**

Also, the equations of higher dimension are way more complicated to solve - they become PED's. How do we even go about getting the $E$ field profile for the 2- or 3- dimensional case?

Edit: I figure the situation there is similar to that of a parallel plate capacitor. However, for this we need to assume that the $z-y$ crossection is infinite. But some books even explicitly treat a diode as a 1D device. How can these two formulations coexist?

Comment: The diode may be three dimensional, but the current flow through the diode is one dimensional and follows the direction of the field so its treated as a 1D problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symmetry reduces the full 3-dimensional equation to a 1-dimensional equation. Gauss's law is:

$$\nabla\cdot \vec E = \frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$

In a diode, suppose it is oriented along the $x$-axis. We assume we have translational and rotational symmetry in the $y-z$ plane, which means $\partial \vec E_y/ \partial y = 0$ and $\partial \vec E_z/ \partial z = 0$. Thus the full equation reduces to simply $\partial \vec E_x/ \partial x = \rho/\epsilon_0$.

---

Edit: Another reason why we only consider the $x$-direction is, instead of considering the electric-field vector at every point throughout the diode, instead consider the electric field averaged over the entire diode, producing one single vector. With a potential difference purely existing along the $x$-direction, certainly the only component of $E$ which shall remain after averaging will be $E_x$.

Also, consider the geometry of a diode. The depletion region at the p-n junction has an average width of about 1 $\mu$m. Compare this with standard wire diameter sizes, which at smallest are $\sim500$ $\mu$m. So at most points along the p-n junction, it basically looks like you have an infinite $y-z$ plane. Therefore, you won't lose too much accuracy in assuming that there is an infinite $y-z$ plane when computing $\vec E$. Again, you can also just make the assumption as per the previous paragraph - working with the averaged electric field.

Comment: Why do we assume the symmetries?

Comment: And why do the symmetries you mentioned imply independence of y and z variables?

Comment: The only place where I see a symmetry argument can be made is the exact center of the $x-y$ crossection of the diode. Otherwise, the symmetry can only hold if the $x-y$ crossection of the diode is assumed to be _extending infinitely in all directions_

Comment: I meant $y-z$ crossection, apologies

Comment: @Sgg8 I have made an edit to hopefully make things a bit more clear.